# Possible to link data between two excel workbooks on SharePoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-2010

The question concerns 2 excel files that now reside in SharePoint.  The solution was easy when they were both in Excel, but now the link is unsupported.  I am looking for a workaround...

- Workbook B contains a data set that needs to be linked to cells in Workbook A.
- Workbook A is viewed by the entire department, while Workbook B will remain separate and is used by a smaller group.
- When Workbook B is updated with new data, it should automatically update Workbook A as well.

This seems to be problematic (impossible?) in SharePoint.  I would also be open to having Workbook B live on my hard drive if that helps to link the files.  We are just trying to keep many changes made by many users in sync between documents.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe better served to post on SharePoint.StackExchange.com